# Initialization of inline static data

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, inline-variable

I am wondering how and when static inline data is initialized in C++ (for example in gcc or clang). I know it is a question specific to some architecture and it is not related to the C++ standard.

I know that for static/global non-inline data gcc is using the `.init` and `.fini` sections for constructing and destructing objects with such qualifiers but this won't work for inline static data because it can be initialized in many translation unit so the `init` section will end up with many initializations to do for a single object which is wrong.

Does anyone know how the implementation works?

To be clear I am interested in the implementation of the initialization of those inline variables.

Comment: "Has anyone checked it" trust me, the standards committee (and others) have been over that many, many times. The standard defines the rules *exactly*. All you need to do is "read it".

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP is asking about the implementation in GCC/Clang (presumably on Linux/x86-64), not the standard.

Comment: @walnut yes I want to know how inline variables are implemented in gcc/clang. I know what the standard tells about them

Comment: @walnut I think that the implementation is based on weak symbols so there will be a definition in each object file and the linker chooses only one symbol.what I don't understand is how this variable is initialized which is much more complicated because only one instance needs to be initialized

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is equivalent to that for function-local statics, which also “risk” being initialized repeatedly: an additional **guard variable** is created and checked to make initialization happen just once.  The [assembly](https://www.godbolt.org/z/T7Autj) for this process is pleasingly straightforward.